# Cannot merge branch with commits by former employee - Stash/GIT

Tags: git, github, bitbucket-server

I'm getting error

```
remote: ERROR: 4020ffbb63204e7aeb5431f672ac74f8fc929acd has failed hook 'Enforce_Author': 
<USER> not found in Stash!
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What do you have in `./.git/hooks` directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have some access control mechanisms in place that validate commits authors against current user accounts.  You will need to contact the administrator of your Stash instance to work around this feature, or you will need to use something like `git filter-branch` to rewrite the commits to have a new name/email.

For details on the latter, see the [git-filter-branch man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch), which includes an example of using the `--env-filter` option to do rewrite git author and comitter names/emails.

Comment: Yes That was the issue, I had to rewrite the python hooks on the server side.